# How can I fly for 13 hours with a back pain? On economy

Tags: air-travel

Reclining the chair actually hurts my back. So I need my back to be fully flat, at least for a few hours to give it a break. Alternatively I can lie on my chest or on my sides.

I asked the airline. They said if there's enough empty seats, they could let me move over to a seat with empty 2 neighbor seats. But no guarantee of any kind.

Could it be possible to move to a business seat or is there any other space in the airplane that I can occupy? I wouldn't mind lying at the floor because pain is worse. Potentially bigger problem is if I damage my back, then I'm going to be in pain in the following weeks or months.

PS. I do exercises before, during and after flights. I pay a lot of attention to moving my body slowly and within control to make sure I don't do anything to increase damage or pain. Also using drugs I was given

Comment: is "not flying and saving your back" not an option?

Comment: Could a back brace or lumbar support belt or similar be of help (check with your doctor first though) ?

Comment: There is basically 0 chance there's an empty business/first class seat, they will upgrade people to those seats and it's probably not going to be you if you have to ask this question.  A row of empty seats also pretty much never happens and no, they won't let you lie on the ground for a bunch of fairly obvious reasons  -- first and foremost if there is any unexpected turbulence you'll be thrown like a ragdoll but also you'll be a tripping hazard.  The obvious solution is to not fly economy.

Comment: @eps I mostly agree with your comment, but I've found empty rows of economy seats on countless occasions. There's definitely no guarantee, but it's also a distinct possibility.

Comment: @eps - finding empty rows depends very much on the flight / destination.  During the current restrictions on travel to the USA, transatlantic flights have been almost guaranteed to have empty rows, but that will change in Nov when the restrictions are relaxed

Comment: Doesn't this boil down to whether airlines are allowed to refuse to carry stretcher cases in economy?

Comment: @eps I see no reason why an airline should upgrade an economy passenger into business (or business into first) simply because there are free seats available in the higher class available, even if that customer has reached the highest frequent flyer status. In my experience, empty business class seats definitely do happen and complimentary upgrades are a push-effect rather than a pull-effect: because the *lower* class is overbooked, a priority customer gets pushed up so they don't have to reject any boardings. (This may lead to a domino effect.)

Comment: Will they let you buy 3 seats in a row?

Answer (score 27):

There aren't many answers for this.  I too have lower back pain and sciatica. It sucks.

1. If you get a seat next to you, or ideally 4, you could stretch out.  This is not usually common, although rumour has it planes on average are less full at present, depending on the route.
2. Stretches. Depending on your back injury, speak with a physio beforehand about exercises you could do in the aisle or even in your seat every 30 min or so.
3. Painkillers and Voltaren/deep heat.  Deep heat saves me, seriously. Downside is it has quite the aroma.
4. Upgrade. Pay for premium or business if available.  The pain to your wallet may be worth it to your back, and might be cheaper than physiotherapy bills.
5. Grin and bear it.  Sometimes suffering is the last and only option. It's only 13 hours. It will end. Try and sleep as best as you can.

Unfortunately, lying in the aisle is not an option and is usually banned by most airlines for safety reasons.

Comment: Or buy three seats, under mentioning that you need them for yourself, medical reasons.

Comment: Note that on some aircraft, not all armrest can be raised (I've seen aircraft were 4 seats were actually 2 sets of 2, so you couldn't raise the armrests between the two sets), or not fully. Some seats (especially on emergency exit rows) have fixed armrests as well.

Comment: ThermaCare back warmers are great as well - no aroma. Lots of ibuprofen.

Comment: Refining @Willeke's comment: this is generally known as the "Extra Seat" option, and may be cheaper than an actual ticket (no luggage, no weight, ...). Unclear if 2 "Extra Seat" is possible, though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It is often mentioned as needed if injured abroad and no insurance that covers repatriarion.

Comment: @JonCuster - I know you mean well but this is advice from someone who has never had severe back issues.   If you were someone who had spinal issues (slipped/misaligned disks) you would never say "ThermaCare back warmers are great".   That is what someone with a little back ache does.   The heat from something like that would make that area expand and the expansion of the muscles would put more strain/pain on back and could fully pinch nerve were you can't walk.   Severe back pain - cold/ice.

Comment: @blankip - you assume a lot, but yes, whether hot or cold is best depends on the specific issue. For me it is muscle spasms locking my back in extremely painful positions - heat and ibuprofen help. I was merely adding to other options that could be used in combination.

Comment: If there are empty rows, there shouldn't be any issues switching to one after boarding/take off. I've done it a few times, just to sleep laying down (with shoes off).

Comment: @blankip - well, you basically told me that I've never had severe back pain. And that heat would be no good for it. I have had severe back pain, and heat was the proper way to treat it (both the spasms and the symptoms). And, yes, those ThermaCares do great over 10+ hours.

Comment: @Matthieu The main reason this is usually *much* cheaper (for economy) is because you don't pay most taxes since most of those apply per passenger.

Comment: @blankip [Thermotherapy patients reported significantly less pain compared to cryotherapy and control](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4225921/). But to be fair that's only a medical study with actual patients and not some random guy on the internet, I'd be wary of those too.

Answer (score 13):

One more point: research the plane and the seat carefully before you book. A site like [www.seatguru.com](http://www.seatguru.com)  is good for this. You can check layout, pitch, width and read reviews from other passengers.

The difference can be profound. For example United flies multiple versions of the Boeing 777. The older ones have 3-3-3 seating while the new "high density" ones have 3-4-3 seating in economy. It's the difference between a tolerable experience (even for 16 glorious hours from EWR to HKG) to absolute misery. Consider paying extra or routing differently to avoid a "bad" plane (if possible).

There is small chance that you plane will be swapped out or that seatguru gets it wrong, but this is quite rare.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing you can do but move around during the flight as much as the crew let's you.   I have had severe back issues in different parts of my life.   I was on an overseas flight where I threw up because it got so bad.

You can buy better seats or buy 2 or three seats next to you.   This may make it less painful but its not going to save you.

You for sure cannot count on the airline to help you.   You don't get free upgrades because of a bad back.   Also the gate/ticket counters will always say "if there are open seats next to you we will see what we can do".

No - in 90%+ of the flights I have taken the gate crew makes no attempt to ever talk to the attendants about anything like this.

And to make matters worse empty areas of the airplane are basically treated like a Thunderdome Arena with very little rules.

- If there are open seats some attendants will let you move right after boarding.
- If there are open seats some attendants make passengers wait until after the seatbelt sign has been turned off during take-off.
- I have been on many a flight where one attendant makes up one rule (please sir take your seat) and bam 5 people move right behind you under the orchestration of another attendant.

You can schmooze attendants or try to play the pity case but your results will be somewhat random.   If you are slow because your back hurts, that does not make anything better.   I have always been aggressive claiming space and just assume that once everyone is on the plane I move where I want (doesn't always work).   If it doesn't work you go back and try again later.

I was on a flight where I had staked out an open row.   Teenage girl saw this (and she had an open seat next to her).   Well I got sent back to my seat.   We are climbing in the air and bam... before that seatbelt sign goes off she takes the row - 5 seats... Ok so it's on.  She made a strategic mistakes, she started lounging in the second seat.   I took the middle.   She says - I was about to lay down here.   I say - me too.   Thunderdome!

The pitfalls of staking out an open claim like this though is like others have said not all middle rows let all the arm rests up - ways around this though.   And also if you do get a row like this you cannot really just walk around the plane stretching and stuff or someone is going to claim your ground.   Basically you got to leave a bunch of your crap there (shoes and socks are key) and you need to stay a substantial amount of time before leaving for more than a quick bathroom break.

**Paying a little more option:**  I hate to give an option that costs more because people saying upgrade to business or first class... well I go over to London often.   Around ~1100.   Business is ~4500-6000 and first class ~8000-12000.   But the economy plus are an extra 100-150 each flight.   So might make the trip ~1400.   **Anyways if you can get in the first row of a section of economy plus that is the best you can do for your back.**

Comment: Please do not take your shoes and socks off on a plane! Why not just leave your underwear while you're at it

Comment: asking the flight attendants if you can lay down on the floor in the galley for a while because of your back problems is often not a problem.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- shoes are not comparable to underwear, usually they are not even in contact with the body. If anything, getting rid of the shoes is analogous to taking off a coat.

Comment: @jwenting "asking the flight attendants if you can lay down on the floor in the galley for a while because of your back problems" That sounds like a flight safety issue to me. If the plane needs to be evacuated in a hurry, and someone's lying down in the aisle, then they'd get trampled to death while tripping everyone else up, slowing down the evacuation and potentially causing hundreds of deaths.

Comment: @nick012000 not in the aisle, in the galley. And it won't be for long, maybe 10 minutes to relieve pressure on the back long enough that you can keep going.

Comment: If you can lay down on multiple seats you have to take off your shoes, as those should not be on the seat nor sticking out into the aisle.

Comment: @Muschkopp Being in contact with the body is irrelevant. Your feet smell. Taking your shoes off lets people smell that. That is gross. So is leaving your underwear on a chair

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Your feet only smell because you wear shoes all the time and don't wash your shoes. If you went barefoot, your feet wouldn't smell any worse than your hands (which are biologically very similar). And no one goes around saying that you have to put your hands away because they are stinky.

Comment: @user3067860 So what? People wear shoes and often are spending long, stressful hours in airports and on planes. Even someone anal about their feet smelling nice probably have worse than average smelling feet on planes. Of course people don't say that, because society doesn't make our hands smell?? Plane floors are nasty (although are they worse than the rest of the plane? probably not), so please don't walk around barefoot on a plane then put your feet on a seat. I can't believe I'm having this discussion.

Comment: @user3067860 it’s irrelevant why feet smell. The fact is, they do, and it’s unpleasant to expose others to that smell. Just like there are good reasons why farts smell: it doesn’t suddenly make it any more acceptable.

Comment: "Im in severe back pain, but oh no, your feet might smell a bit".  Not even closely comparable. Deal with it.

Comment: @Stilez Taking off your socks and shoes has nothing to do with the back pain. blankip suggested taking them off to claim your space (and then walking around without them on??) that's just the nastiest way to claim a space. Leave a water bottle or something. Or just recognize you can't claim a seat that isn't yours anyway.

Comment: I cant help your personal.sentiments. i would say though, they arent universal, and they are just that, sentiments. They can be endured, every bit as much as say, back pain can.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- just to clarify, never been on a plane with no socks.   I said socks, not dirty socks I was wearing.   Coat and other things works too.   Often a backpack with electronics is one of the best things because people are afraid to touch "valuables" but didn't want start a huge debate about leaving a backpack with valuable things unattended.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what you're willing to spend (how important the trip is and how frequently you go on these kind of trips), you could consider upgrading to first class. Not all, but quite a handful of airlines provide you an actual bed, sometimes within your own room on the airplane.

Comment: If you spend a little more you could get a private plane.

Comment: This is the right answer, though.  **OP has fallen into a mental trap of "bargain-hunting behavior"**.  That is actually a willful trade between quality and cost, but OP is inculcated into it and has forgotten it is willful. Even though all of us make such willful transactions everyday: an annual smart phone instead of keeping a $100 flip phone every 5 years.  A nice car instead of a Chevy Spark. Better food than Burger King etc.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Assuming of course that OP can afford more than economy. If they don't have enough money to pay for it (which is quite possible considering how much first class costs relative to most people's income levels), then choice is removed from the equation. Or rather, the real choice is between flying economy or not flying at all.

Comment: @JBentley That's a bit the point I was trying to touch, how necessary is this flight? If it's a transit flight from the place of the accident (that lead to the pain) back home, it might be worth it to consider as a one-time option, even if it would be out of budget usually. If it's a holiday vacation kind of trip, the expectations of flying economy need to be managed properly, as this is what you get.

Comment: @JBentley my point is, that "can afford" thing is largely illusory/fictitious. People *find a way* to afford it.   If economy is off the table for OP, that simply means flying is more expensive, but it was much more expensive still in the 70s (by % of mean income) and everyone still flew. Airfares have been in free-fall for decades.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - not buying your take on this.   He's suggesting first class, which can run a multiple of 10x.    In your world a family of 4 is going to Disney World for a week and really lowballing that vacation it costs them 8k total.   So you are saying that if they can go on slightly more enjoyable vacation... 80k?   Another way to put it and I have a bad back...  I can buy a nice car for my teenager for the difference between economy and first class on that length of a trip.   I'll rough it and buy my kid a 9k car before shelling out $600 an hour for a better seat.

Comment: @blankip then business, or work with the airline or a broker to get first class seats cheaper. Heck, Spirit's big front seats are only $50 extra.  I think you are trying to extrapolate my argument to the absurd by calling it a "world".  A family of 4 doesn't all have back problems.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - your comments work for shorter flights.   For transcontinental there is really no brokering your way into 1st class - especially COVID times.   The first class is always full, economy no.    If I take a 13 hour flight it will be on the low end 800, realistically 1200.    Business is around 5-6k and first class 9-15k.      There's no equivalents to what you are talking about.   There was that one airline that went to iceland that was cheapo... but their "first class" was like economy plus.

Comment: Well those prices are preposterous, obviously only play-toys for the rich.  So then it's a demand issue @blankip, like trying to do home construction right now LOL.  Anyway if biz class is a month's pay for a typical person, well, in the 1970s, traveling **in coach** was a month's pay, and first class *then* had the amenities of biz *now*.   So it's still a matter of perspective. A 70s person would consider $5000 the normal price, pay it happily, and think they got a free upgrade to first class.  It's only the carnal knowledge of current coach pricing that makes $5000 seem absurd.

Comment: Or buying three tickets (if first class is really 10x economy, this would be cheaper)/

Answer (score 5):

Break the flight into two 7 hours segments. Sleep/Lie down in between the segments at the airport. One advantage of this is that the flight is most likely cheaper then a non-stop one. Disadvantage is the trip will take forwever.

Comment: That does not help.   You are just in a plane longer, sitting in airport longer.   As a person with a bad back I would never do this.

Comment: @blankip If you are in airports with napping facilities (like LHR, HKG and SIN) why would this not help?

Comment: @OleTange - not relevant.   I have never been in an airports with an open bed to lay in.   Counting the time you spend in the seats before take off at the airport, the time on the runway, the time after landing ... being a person with a bad back this is not good advice.   Sure it could work... but 98% of the time it will make it worse.

Comment: The Beijing airport has an in airport hotel.  The rooms are tiny - just a bed and a TV.  There is a communal bathroom.  It is perfect for a long layover.  I don't know why every major airports does not have amenities like this.

Comment: @emory - OK... really not the point.   There are tons of airports with connecting hotels.   I don't see how that is relevant.   With this advice I will for sure spend more time in tight seats.   I could have 4 people massage my back as they wheel me through the terminal... that isn't relevant to taking two planes...

Comment: Only places to nap in most airports is on the floor, and those floors are usually tiles, they're HARD. As a back patient myself I know this all too well. I've had flights where I've asked the flight attendants if it was ok for me to lay down on the floor for a while, usually they're fine with me doing that in the galley as long as there's no meal service going on. It helps. Other flights just sitting on the floor instead of in an airliner seat helps.

Comment: @blankip I am talking about a hotel that is in the airport not "connected to it".  If my back was aching after a flight, I would not want to get in a bus for a ride to the "connecting airport" which is what ends up happening most of the time.  I would want immediate rest.  Whether that is good enough or not is a different question.

Answer (score 4):

Right now airlines are packing flights as full as possible in an effort to recoup losses from the past 18 months. If you're looking for extra room in economy or free upgrades you better have status(which from your asking means you most likely don't). To be completely honest, if you need to lay down for a long flight then you should pony up for the First/Business Class or Premium Economy upgrade. If you can't do that then I'd highly advise postponing your trip.

If the trip is for business then assuming you have seen a doctor regarding your back issues tell your manager that you have medical issues and that you will be upgrading your seat to first class in order to alleviate them.

If none of the above are possible, make an appointment to go see your doctor and ask them how you can alleviate the back pain. Physical therapy and chiropractic appointments did wonders for my sciatica to the point to where it took 2 weeks for most issues to subside and 8 weeks for all symptoms to go away.

Edited: Changed the business use case to specify managerial approval.

Comment: Check your company policy and talk to your Manager before buying a First Class ticket you expect to be reimbursed for!  There may be special processes or they may cancel your trip, don't end up out of pocket!!

Comment: I have to strongly agree with Alan Dev. You should *not* buy a First Class or even Business Class seat without approval from your line manager. What you *can* do is tell your line manager that for medical reasons you can only fly First Class or not at all. But spending what can sometimes turn out to be 10x of someone else's money without telling anyone is not a good idea.

Comment: @AlanDev Even if it is out of pocket, it's still a business expense so you'd probably be able to deduct it from your taxes.

Comment: A friend found acupuncture to be highly effective, even though he didn't believe in it. Someone persuaded him he had nothing to lose by trying it, and it worked. A similar argument might apply to hypnotherapy (in this case I don't know anybody who has tried it).

Comment: @AlanDev Your probably right, I've edited the answer to reflect this. I've always been a ask for forgiveness type of person than to ask for permission.

Comment: @nick012000 that's going to depend on the tax code in your area ...

Answer (score 3):

I have arthritis pretty much throughout my spine and just had pain block injections last week, so sitting in economy while flying to SE Asia to visit my wife's family can be excruciating.  I usually don't recline my seat either, as that seems to make it worse, but sometimes you have little choice if the people in front and back of you are inclined.  What I've learned to do is to keep a supply of Panadeine only for flying.  Panadeine isn't available in the US where I live so I have to bring it back from our trips, or if Canada's open it's available there.  There's just enough codeine in it to keep the pain knocked back, but not so much that I get nauseous from taking it (like I would with prescription Tylenol III or similar).  You need to stay on top of your pain, I know that I need to take one 500mg Panadeine every 4 hours or so to remain pain free enough to be somewhat comfortable, maybe even sleep (rare).

**Edit**: we almost always upgrade to economy+ for the extra legroom.  My wife doesn't need it, but at 6'-2" it makes a difference for me even if it costs us an extra $600 or so for our two seats to be upgraded.

Obviously taking a narcotic is less than desirable, but it's what I've learned to do.  I also bring Voltaren or a generic for diclofenac gel (if you're in the US, both Walmart & Costco sell a generic now that's quite reasonable).  Yes, it's a bit smelly, but it's not an unpleasant smell, and it doesn't last long as its absorbed into your skin.  It also wasn't available in the US until very recently, so I'd have to bring it back from trips like the Panadeine.

**Also, Panadeine's not exactly legal to have in the US, although I've never had a customs agent confiscate it on either end of the trip.**  I also never fly into Singapore or Malaysia with prescription narcotics of any kind except Tramadol (which is not on either of their illegal drugs schedules, something you do NOT want to mess with over there).  **Do your own research and don't trust mine, I haven't flown to SE Asia (or anywhere else) for several years so things might have changed.**

We also spend time on checking out our plane's seating arrangement to locate the best seats where there's some extra room for a bit of stretching and the fewest people around us, usually toward the tail of the plane.  My wife is small, so she can curl up in a seat, but I'm football player sized, so I'm generally bigger than the seats can comfortably accommodate.  As long as we're seated together, this isn't a big deal because I can just use some of her unused space so my shoulders aren't out in the aisle (another reason to check the seating arrangements to maximize the aisle width so you're not getting bumped by the cart every time they go by).  Some flights are really good about not hitting you or at least letting you know they're coming (China Air, Delta), others seems to do it deliberately to punish you for being in the way (United).

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to take the same trip by train?

There's a lot more ability to move up and down the aisle, and there may exist sleeper facilities on the route.

Even if only part of the trip can be via train, a connecting flight will then be shorter and perhaps more tolerable, or can be replaced by a rental car where you're moving about in the seat a bit more.

Comment: A 13 hour flight by train? I do not know about intercontinental trains.

Comment: @Willeke nowhere in the question says it was an intercontinental flight, over water.  And the follow-on comment about doing part of the trip by train remains valid.

Comment: And replace 13 hours of flight with some hours of flight and a few days in a train. I am pro train but in this case you miss the mark.

Comment: @Willeke I mean, it doesn't apply to the exact question, but someone might google how to fly with back pain for their five hour LA-DC flight and find this answer useful.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, as I said in my comment, I am pro train but replacing a many hours flight with a train will get you to a several days train journey or one in high speed trains where you will have to change trains a few times and your seat will be no better than those in planes. I was willing to travel Amsterdam to Napels by train (cancelled due to covid) but that  was 24+ hours by train instead of less than 3 hours in a plane (including the wait between boarding and the actual start.) And €150 for the train journey instead of €65 or less for a flight (and budget is part of the question.)

Comment: I would think in this case, the question is finding a passenger-carrying ship.